# Is it possible to set additional languages using C# package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1?

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

Is it possible to set additional languages using C# package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1 in RecognitionConfig.AlternativeLanguageCodes?

In version 1.0.0-beta02 I see that this field is only readable, though in Google Cloud documentation it was mentioned, that we can set up to three additional languages.

How can I do it? Does anyone know, is there a newer version of this package?

Comment: Welcome to Stakoverflow Did you do any research? Can you show some of your effort...

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried to earch for new version on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1, but I see, that it is the newest version...

Comment: Here is code for RecognitionConfig

var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Flac,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                EnableWordTimeOffsets = true,
                LanguageCode = "ru-RU",
                EnableSpeakerDiarization = true,
                MaxAlternatives = 1,
                //AlternativeLanguageCodes = ???,
                AudioChannelCount = 1,
                EnableWordConfidence = true,
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile(test_file_path));

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below should get you going

var RecogCfg = new Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1.RecognitionConfig
        {

```
       // Encoding = EncodeType,
        //SampleRateHertz = Int32.Parse(SampleRate),                
        LanguageCode = Lang,
       // EnableAutomaticPunctuation = true,
        //EnableWordTimeOffsets = true,
        MaxAlternatives = 5,
        Model= "default"
    };

    //add one or more alternative language codes
    RecogCfg.AlternativeLanguageCodes.Add("<Language Code 1>");
    RecogCfg.AlternativeLanguageCodes.Add("<Language Code 2>");
```